# GET Data from Weather Resource to display on Website

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I would like to create an html page that brings data from the following URL:

https://www.aviationweather.gov/cgi-bin/json/MetarJSON.php?density=all&bbox=-81.97833633,33.74239834,-79.92494965,36.77610887

The page from this url produces a JSON view from within a browser

My HTML page needs to use this data and convert it into the table below. I've seen many examples and have tried reverse-engineering them however I have been unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Page Should look like this. Ideally, Each record displayed would appear in the table within the  Tags

`

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>data</td>
<td>id</td>
<td>site</td>
<td>prior</td>
<td>obsTime</td>
<td>temp</td>
<td>dewp</td>
<td>wspd</td>
<td>wdir</td>
<td>ceil</td>
<td>cover</td>
<td>visib</td>
<td>fltcat</td>
<td>altim</td>
<td>slp</td>
<td>rawOb</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
... for each record
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

`

Ok here was an attempt at reverse engineering something I did with a GOOGLE Calendar App.

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      //Jquery's ajax request
      $.ajax({
             type:'GET',
             url:'https://www.aviationweather.gov/cgi-bin/json/MetarJSON.php?density=all&bbox=-81.97833633,33.74239834,-79.92494965,36.77610887',
             dataType: 'json',
             async:true
             }).done(function(data){
                     //once we get a successful response this callback function
                     //gets fired, and "data" contains the parsed json file .
                     //here we iterate over the object array
                     $.each(data.properties, function(i, property){
                            //append data to the list.
                            if(property.data = "METAR"){
                            $('table.isSearch tbody').append(`<tr><td width="150">${property.id}</td><td width="200">${property.fltcat}</td><td>${property.ceil}</td></tr>`);
                            }
                            });

                     }).fail(function(e){
                             error(e);
                             });

      </script>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <td>id</td>
  <td>fltcat</td>
  <td>ceil</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Could you show what you've tried?

Comment: Sure. I have tried using this witht he exception of pointing to the online URL for getting the data: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp

Comment: Sure. I have tried using this with the exception of pointing to the online URL for getting the data: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp

I have also tried this and still nothing: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp

I have tried many, most of which use a Jquery/ajax call 
$.ajax({
             type:'GET',
             url:'https://www.aviationweather.gov/cgi-bin/json/MetarJSON.php?density=all&bbox=-81.97833633,33.74239834,-79.92494965,36.77610887',
             dataType: 'json',
             async:true

Comment: The problem I'm having is iterating through the data fields I want to display based on the URL output. 

Im not sure how to loop through the items to then display into a table.